# Publishing React Native application using expo

Tags: react-native

I am trying to publish my application on iphone using expo client. When I send the link from my mackbook to iphone. I got an error saying "There was a problem loading the requested app. It looks like you may be using the LAN URL. make sure your device is on the same network as the server or try using a tunnel." I am on the same network. I checked the network twice. These are the steps that I followed 1) I started the application by giving the command in terminal window saying "npm start". 2) I choose the option "s" and then I was prompted to enter my iphone #. I entered the phone number and as soon as I did that, I got the text message on my phone saying "exp://10.21... . I clicked on this link and started getting the error message "There was a problem loading the requested app. It looks like you may be using the LAN URL. make sure your device is on the same network as the server or try using a tunnel." When I choose the option i. Option"i" is to run the application on emulator. I can successfully run the application on emulator, but when I send the link to my iphone, it does not work.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I really need help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded expo xde and that compiled my project and send the permanent link to my iphone and android and it worked well. Directly doing npm start does not send the right link because of some tunneling issues.I downloaed expo XDE from this link:

[Expo XDE](https://github.com/expo/xde/releases)